# .NET Regex, only numeric, no spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that accepts only numerical values and no spaces.
I'm currently using:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

which works fine, but it accepts values that consist ONLY of spaces. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Does \d+ work? It should match a sequence of one or more digits.

Answer (score 14):

The reason why is that `*` will accept 0 or more.  A purely empty string has 0 numbers and hence meets the requirements.  You need 1 or more so use `+` instead.

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]+)$
```

**EDIT**

Here is Andrews more robust and simpler solution.

```
^\d+$
```

Comment: Cheers for the quick answer, however it will still pass a string that has only spaces :(

Comment: Your suggested regex `^(0|[1-9][0-9]+)$` does not support numbers greater than zero and less than ten.

Comment: But doesn't * only apply to the last set of digits? OP is matching either 0 or 1-9 followed by zero or more 0-9.

Comment: @Damage are you sure you're actually utilizing the Regex framework in .Net correctly? a simple regex such as ^\d+$ should never ever match anything but unsigned integer text strings. Try posting your .Net code

Answer (score 1):

this regex works perfecttly

```
^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9])?$
```

Comment: Are decimals not "only numeric, no spaces"?  I feel this is an unfair downvote.  If the asker only wants integers, no spaces, the question title should reflect that and at the moment I'm inclined to downvote the question as a result.